# Radio Button issue in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, radio-button

I have a table view in which I'm loading some data i'm trying to make radio button on that data, but when i select any cell it does not deselect other it is working as a check box . I'm confused where i'm doing mistake, My code is this,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    radiobtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    radiobtn.frame = CGRectMake(30, 60, 30, 30);

    [radiobtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [radiobtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rights.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [radiobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = radiobtn;

}

cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0) green:(0) blue:(0) alpha:1];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellDragStateLifting;
return cell;

}

-(void)radiobtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
if([sender isSelected])
{
    [sender setSelected:NO];
}

else
{
    [sender setSelected:YES];
}
}
```

It is looking like this, 
[image]

Comment: Add `self.tableView.reloadData() `in the end of your `radiobtn` method.

Comment: Where is the code to deselect the other cells?

Comment: radiobtn method. @vadian

Comment: No, `radiobtn` changes only the selection status of the `sender` which is the currently pressed button. You need to save the index path of the selected cell. If a button is pressed deselect the current cell, select the new one and update the index path.

Comment: it is just reload the data but not deslecting the item. @biloshkurskyi.ss

Comment: You should have some property for each element in `dataArray`, and process it too inside the `radiobtn:(UIButton *)sender.` `reloadData()` reload all cells and you will have updated data.

Comment: @biloshkurskyi.ss `reloadData()` is unnecessarily expensive. Actually you have to change only two cells which can be reloaded individually.

Comment: @vadian I partly agree with you, because it dependence from the logic. Reload data give you result in any conditions without saving previous indexes and manual it processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UIButton *radiobtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    radiobtn.frame = CGRectMake(30, 60, 30, 30);
    radiobtn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [radiobtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [radiobtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rights.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
//    [radiobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = radiobtn;

}

cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0) green:(0) blue:(0) alpha:1];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellDragStateLifting;
return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
button.selected = YES;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
button.selected = NO;
}
```